# ¡hola!, ¿cómo puedo establecer un TIPO DE LETRA para todo un documento PDF en R Markdown?

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown, markdown

Quiero que mi documento PDF salga con letra Monserrat siempre, tanto tablas como gráficas. Por el momento he logrado cambiar la letra en gráficas, pero sigo sin poder hacerlo en tablas.

He intentado ponerlo en un chunk global con knitr::opts_chunk$set(), pero no logro encontrar la función específica para hacerlo.